# Altered values of GeoTIFF after vector extraction.QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've downloaded a LAI (Leaf Area Index) in GeoTIFF format from https://land.copernicus.eu. After I extract some specific area via raster-extraction-extract by mask the raster values are altered. Before I got specific LAI values between 0 an 7 after the extraction I got in return Digital Numbers, values ranging from 0 to 170.

**First**: I don't know why this is happening and i want to understand it.
**Second**: I want my values to remain the same as the input

My version of QGIS is 3.4.

[image: LAI before vector extraction]

[image: LAI after vector extraction]

Comment: Seems like your values got strechted to 0 to 255.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then I suggest you [edit] your question to clarify your actual question: do you just want to know why this happened? Or do you want the two rasters to have the same ranges? Or something else?